# Car stalls couple times after start-up

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, stall, lancer

I own a 2004 mitsubishi lancer, everytime i start driving the car for the day it always stalls when coming to a stop even if the car is in neutral. After driving for about 5 minutes, it no longer stalls anymore. I thought the car just needed to get up to temperature, but that didn't seem to solve it, can it be a problem with something electrical or the clutch itself?

Comment: If the symptoms go away after 5 minutes then it does sound temperature related. If you drive for 20 minutes, stop the car then restart does it still stall?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair, BTW :o)

Comment: I've tried letting the car get up to temperature. After 5 minutes of driving around everything works fine. There's no problem if I restart the car after 20 minutes.